# Microsoft LUIS mistakes different letters for the same one

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I'm using several large List Entities in Microsoft LUIS. To import these lists in different LUIS apps, and also for a more convenient workflow, I want to import these lists as JSON files. In general, this works but for some lists I get the following error message:

[image: Error message while using the import]

Unfortunately, this error message doesn't provide any clue to problematic entries. So, I tried to make smaller lists and eventually found the problem. I had these two items in the list:
"A**th**ena" and "A**þ**ena". According to wikipedia, **þ** is an Icelandic letter which is pronouced similarly to **th**, and was therefore often replaced in the past. However, those two words lead to a 409 error if entered manually.

[image]
[image]

Of course, I can just remove one of the entries, and also handle the þ letter in a script, but I would like to know if there is a list of letters that are treated in the same way, which may lead to the same issue. I didn't find anything in the documentation. If you deal with many large entity lists that may grow in the future, it is not very practical to track down those cases individually.

**Edit**
Also I found that the letter **æ** is interpreted as **ae**.